# Not able to select multiple picklist values using lightning:select

Tags: lightning-aura-components, ui, lightningselect

Lightning Ui namespace is deprecating soon hence we are migrating Ui namespace tags to the lightning namespace.  We have used the below tag to select multi picklist values with the Ui namespace. Now salesforce suggesting to use Use `lightning:select` or `lightning:combobox` .

If we use `lightning:select` or `lightning:combobox`  not able to select multiple picklist values. Could anyone please help me with this?

I have tried using `multiple="true"​​​​​​​` in the lightning select tag but is not accepting.

```
<ui:inputSelect multiple="true" class="multiple" aura:id="InputSelectMultiple" change="{!c.onMultiSelectChange}">
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="Any"/>
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="Open"/>
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="Closed"/>
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="Closed Won"/>
 </ui:inputSelect>
```

Thanks,
Anil Kumar

Comment: Consider using `lightning:dualListbox` for multi select options. Also, note all components in `ui:` namespace are deprecated and will be removed soon.

Comment: Thank you for the response Rahul.. As per below link salesforce suggesting to use lightning:select   https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_aura_ui_deprecate.htm#:~:text=We%20plan%20to%20end%20support,versions%20of%20the%20Salesforce%20app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of lightning:select or lightning:combobox support multiple select (as per docs). Lightning:dualListBox is the appropriate component for this-

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:dualListbox/example

Comment: Hi Nagen,  Thanks for the reply. Client is asking not to use duallistbox since they expecting same look and feel of ui:inputSelect. Do we have any other option.

Comment: I don't any of the base components can help you then. You can always build a custom component using the Lightning design system combo-box [blueprint] (https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/combobox/#Multiple-selections) . There's an example i found - https://cafeforce.com/create-multi-select-combobox-picklist-in-lightning-salesforce/

Comment: Thank you Nagen...

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `lightning:dualListbox`, See the excerpts from the docs:

**[lightning:combobox](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:combobox/documentation)**

> lightning:combobox is an input element that enables single selection
> from a list of options. The result of the selection is stored as the
> value of the input. Multiple selection is currently not supported. To
> support multiple selection, use lightning:dualListbox instead.

**[lightning:select](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:select/documentation)**

> A lightning:select component creates an HTML select element. This
> component uses HTML option elements to create options in the dropdown
> list, enabling you to select a single option from the list. Multiple
> selection is currently not supported. To support multiple selection,
> use lightning:dualListbox instead.

If you want to create a similar UI as Combobox, then consider building your own custom component.

**Also, note that [Aura Components in the ui Namespace Are Deprecated](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_aura_ui_deprecate.htm)**